# Installing Magento 2.4.1-p1 on a developer's local getting an error after running static-content:deploy -f

Tags: magento2.4.1

I'm installing Magento 2.4.1-p1 on a developers local using docker to create the environment.
I have installed Magento and imported the DB

and run:

#This run just fine

composer update -vvv
#This run just fine

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

#This run just fine

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

#Get the error here

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

#Error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Config\ReaderInterface in /www/projectname/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /www/projectname/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewo...', Array)
#1 /www/projectname/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Framewo...')
#2 /www/projectname/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...')
#3 /www/projectname/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\Framewo...', NULL, 'reader', 'Magento\Framewo...')
#4 /www/projectname/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.p in /www/projectname/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121

I have tried deleting generated and var in app root, and flushed redis container

Any solution or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: If you copied the database from a pre-existing location, make sure you updated the crypt key in env.php

Comment: @rlock are you able to find solution for this?